# Resize proportionally and crop image in any aspect like top right,top left..... on html5canvas

Tags: html5-canvas

**Code**

```
canvas.width=900 //cropping
canvas.height=414 //cropping
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 900, img.height * (900/img.width)); //resize propportionally
document.body.appendChild(canvas); //show final image
```

I want to crop the image not only from top right, but also from, top left, center, bottom left, bot right. How would I do that?

Comment: Take a look at the extended form of `context.drawImage`. It will both crop and resize your image.

Comment: @markE I tried the the drawimage function to resize the image(1024x1024) to 900x900 and then crop it to 900x414 from the top right direction .ctx.drawImage(image, 124, 610,900, 900, 0, 0, 900, 414);  I think my code is wrong cuz I never got the answer that I wanted. Can you adjust my code ?

Comment: `ctx.drawImage(img, cropX,cropY, cropWidth, cropHeight, 0,0, cropWidth*scale, cropHeight*scale)` where `scale=Math.min((resizedImgWidth/originalImgWidth), (resizedImgHeight/originalImgHeight))`